# Gerund and infinitives

Tags: infinitive-vs-gerund

I hear everyday people use gerund and infinitive with nouns and pronouns instead of simple verbs. For Example: "Instead of me calling you ........ "or, "The minister to resign next month". These sentences confuse me, because I learned that infinitives and gerunds are used with verbs as nouns, subjects, or objects; but I never learned anywhere that gerunds and infinitives are used with nouns and pronouns. Please help!

Comment: In your first example, "me" is the subject of the subordinate clause _me calling you_, which is functioning as complement to the preposition "of". Your second example looks like a headline from a newspaper or the Internet, and has the verb "be" omitted". In full, it would be _The minister is to resign next month_, where  the infinitival clause is predicative complement of the verb "be". There's nothing at all unusual or ungrammatical about either sentence.

Comment: user47388 when are you coming back to visit us again?

Answer (score 1):

Gerunds can take objects where they make sense.

> Walking makes us healthier.
>
> Walking the dog makes the dog healthier.
>
> Giving is required by the church
>
> Giving 20 dollars to the IRS is required by law.

Object or possessive pronouns can be put in front of *-ing* words to identify the "subject".  I think possibly in the case of using an object pronoun, the *-ing* word technically becomes a participial adjective, but I'm not sure.

> I walked to be healthier.
>
> Me walking makes me healthier, but probably not someone with a broken foot.
>
> I gave my sister two dollars
>
> Me giving my sister two dollars resulted in my brother getting jealous.